# How to reach to one chain when hard fork is performed?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

Assume that reward policy of Ethereum is changed from 3eth to 1eth.

Hard fork is ongoing but, there are miners who don't consider updating their software.

what happens?

The miner who did update will record reward of coinbase transaction as 1eth, but the miner who didn't update will record reward of coinbase transaction as 3eth.

Assume that number of miners is 10 in the world. three people did update and others didn't. three people know the reward is 3eth but seven people know the reward is 7eth. it result in remains inconsistent between two groups.

My questions :

1. The senario explained above cannot do hard fork. blockchain will be got screwed if the blockchain initiate hard fork. so how to successfully achieve chain consistency?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original chain would still work as long as there are still miners but since there is barely anybody using it, it would be worth close to nothing.

1) To achieve "chain consistency" the fork needs to be popular with users to stop them from just staying on the old network.

Let me know if you need clarifying.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Out of curiosity, anyone can hard fork the Ethereum? because Ethereum is open software. but probability of success is extremely very low.
It means that we can recognize two points. one is that trust of software needs popular developer such as Vitalic, Joh sepun, etc and second is that we need to gather miner that has powerful hash power in order to make maintain activation of network.

Comment: @Hyunsoo anyone can fork Ethereum (github.com/Ethereum) and what you said is correct.